# Problem with bypassSecurityTrustHtml and UTF-8

Tags: angular, sanitization

I have a pipe to mark some HTML-code as safe. But my problem is that some characters get transformed into a square when I use it. [image: Here is an image that shows the problem...]

The pipe looks like this:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform, SecurityContext } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Pipe({
   name: 'safeHtml'
})
export class SafeHtmlPipe implements PipeTransform {

constructor(private sanitized: DomSanitizer) {}

transform(value: string) {
 return this.sanitized.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(value);
}
}
```

And the HTML-code:

```
<div [innerHTML]="feedItem.content | safeHtml"></div>
```

Does anyone has an idea of what it can be?

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting an html from any content management system, angular will strip out target=“_blank” and some other element properties

If you are binding the innerHTMl without safeHTML angular will strip out some of the element properties .

If you use safeHtml angular will ignore will not strip.

Whatever special characters squares icons you are seeing the UI, it will be gone if you use safeHtml

Make sure add this pipe in module

I hope you got the answer